# How to force a method to be called at some point

Tags: c#, dispose

I have an object implementing `IDisposable`and I want to do some job on the Dispose involving others objects. How can I be sure  that this job is performed. Currently the processing is done inside a if. I can not remove it outside the if, right ?

NB : _innerObject may or may continue to live after MyClass instance is dead.

```
    private OtherClass _innerObject;
    ~MyClass()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed)
            return;

        if (disposing)
        {
            _innerObject.DoSomeJob();
        }
        _disposed = true;
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "a job" ?

Comment: you should look into this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @AK_ my issue with the finalization is that I am not sure of the state of _innerObject. I was thinking to add the _innerObject to a static list on MyClass and remove it once the Dispose done. But I don't find these very clean...

Comment: please explain what you are trying to do, and why....

Comment: @AK_ I am trying to force a method to be called on a managed object at some point. Real reason does not matter, let's take the question as a general purpose. (_innerObject needs to restore some state when MyClass is Disposed/Finalized)

Comment: OK. if it doesnt matter, then call it in the Constructor...

Comment: @AK_ Let be a bit more precise : this need to be called once MyClass instance work was done. So I only see either the finalizer or the dispose, but how ?

Comment: well how about writing it in the dispose , checking that _innerObject is not null and still alive and well, and using the finalizer to call dispose? as in the MSDN examples?

Comment: As far as I know, I can't use _innerObject during finalization (it may already have been finalized). (NB : I do not have the lead on this Class)

Comment: Thats why i said you should check if it's still ok on the dispose. Also finalization ca allso happen during normal opperation, an the program closing

Comment: How can I check that the state of _innerObjet is correct ? _innerObject not being null does not mean that his state is correct.

Answer (score 1):

What does the call to innerObject represent?

For shutdown related methods, you can use events on AppDomain (e.g., ProcessExit/DomainUnload). If you need to clean up resources associated with MyClass, you can take the approach you've taken, but there is no assurance that `DoSomeJob` will be called. Another approach is to enable code analysis, and fail on [CA2000](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182289.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You *can't* have such a guarantee.  `IDisposable` is the best that you can do, but it still relies on the consumers of your type to properly dispose of every instance that is created.  If they don't, there isn't anything that you can really do about it.

Comment: @AK_ There are plenty of ways of creating a program that doesn't finalize all of the objects it creates.  And the OP already has a finalizer; it can add *something* over not having it, but it's still far from a guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

Having read the comments I would say that you can guarantee that _innerObject is not finalized before MyClass by inheriting OtherClass from CriticalFinalizerObject. But this seems like a some hack